# Invalid character in JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

i have the following JSON code:

```
JSON_keyDataGrid = "{\"TABLE_DATA\":{\"COL_DATA\":[{\"field\":\"col_0\",\"title\":\"&lt;a href=\"#\" onclick=\"alert(0);\"&gt;CODE&lt;/a&gt;\",\"halign\":\"center\",\"align\":\"center\",\"width\":\"250\",\"sortable\":\"true\"},{\"field\":\"col_1\",\"title\":\"&lt;a href=\"#\" onclick=\"alert(0);\"&gt;NAME&lt;/a&gt;\",\"halign\":\"center\",\"align\":\"center\",\"width\":\"250\",\"sortable\":\"true\"}],\"ROW_DATA\":[{\"col_0\":\"&lt;a href=\"#\" onclick=\"alert(1);\"&gt;11KAN&lt;/a&gt;\",\"col_1\":\"&lt;a href=\"#\" onclick=\"alert(1);\"&gt;KAN&lt;/a&gt;\"}]}}"


tableData = JSON.parse(JSON_keyDataGrid);   //the error occurred here
```

When I do JSON.parse() it gives an invalid character, I don't understand why.

I checked whether the string is valid using the link:
[JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Please could anyone help me here,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jsonlint:

```
{
    "TABLE_DATA": {
        "COL_DATA": [{
            "field": "col_0",
            "title": "&lt;a href="#
            " onclick="
            alert(0);
            "&gt;CODE&lt;/a&gt;",
```

Note the `#` after the closing `"` on the value of the `title` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't notice that there.... However i copy pasted the line as it is on the JSON lint  url and clicked on validate. It didn't show me that error there..

Comment: @D_ROCKS: My guess is you did the whole string, which is valid JSON because it's just a string. What you need to do is look at the string's *content* and use that. E.g., `"foo"` is valid JSON: It's a string. But `foo` is not valid JSON. Similarly, if I'm guessing right, you checked the `"{\"TABLE_DATA\":...}"` string when what you needed to check was its *contents*, `{"TABLE_DATA":...}`. A string *literal* is not the same as the string.